# Implement multi threading with Apache for a Flask Server on a Windows Server

Tags: python, windows, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a Python based web application which I developed using Flask. I was able to implement multi threading in flask easily via the *threaded = True* option in app.run method. Now that I am deploying it in production, I can't get multithreading to work using the same configuration.

Here is how my code app.py looks :

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

def notifications():

        msg = "random email message"

        try :
            em.sendMail(msg, subscribers)
        except Exception as e :
            print (e)

    t.Timer(MAILFREQUENCY,notifications).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = "0.0.0.0",debug = False, port=PORT, threaded=True)
```

I am extremely new to Apache, so maybe I am missing some configuration. Here is what my web.wsgi file looks like

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '<path for app.py folder>')

from app import app as application
```

the httpd-vhosts.conf file has been configured as below :

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerAdmin admin-name-here
        ServerName  localhost:8000
        WSGIScriptAlias / "<path>/web.wsgi"
        DocumentRoot "<path>"
        <Directory "<path>">


                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog "<path>/error.log"
        CustomLog "<path>" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone please tell me what modifications I need to make the email notification thread run. Right now I dont see it being called at all

Comment: So you want a notification to be sent whenever a query is received by a specific endpoint of your API ?

Comment: No, this is just an example. The email method just sends out regular updates about the application(I have removed the method to get updates for simplicity). This thread needs to run in the background. It isn't triggered by a query. It runs every few seconds(defined by variable MAILFREQUENCY in this example)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a [Flask application factory](https://hackersandslackers.com/demystifying-flask-application-factory/): It will give you more flexibility. I recently encountered the issue of running some lines of code before starting the app. You could start a separate process dedicated to sending notifications before starting your app. First create a folder **app** in your root folder with a file **__init__.py** that contains something like this (to adapt to your specific needs):

```
import ...

from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

"""
    flask application factory
"""
def create_app( some_parameter ):

    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping( SOME_PARAMETER = some_parameter )

    """
        notification function to run in separate process
    """
    def notifications(notification_frequency):
        msg = "some message"
        while 1:
            try :
                em.sendMail(msg, subscribers)
            except Exception as e :
                print (e)
            time.sleep(notification_frequency)

    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello World!'

    # start your notification process
    notification_frequency = 60
    p = Process(target=notifications, args=(notification_frequency,))
    p.start()

    return app
```

Your application factory must be called `create_app`. You can pass it some parameters if you want. In this case the notification process will always send the same message, but you could also create a [Queue](https://kite.com/python/docs/multiprocessing.Queue) and have your endpoints to send your notification process some content. In your root folder the content of your **web.wsgi** file would be:

```
from app import create_app

application = create_app("YOLO")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!   ```AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'create_app.<locals>.notifications'\r``` I get this error on restarting the server after the recommended modifications

Comment: On which line of code does it throw this exception ? Also please recheck my answer as I made some modifications

Comment: ```  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/CoolSign/SM DataWatcher Web\\app.py", line 29, in create_app\r
     p.start()\r   AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'create_app.<locals>.notifications'\r```  I copied over your code and tried to run as is, but I get this error now. Were you able to run this?

Comment: I just tried the code and it works (just rename app to application in wsgi.py). But I am not using apache2, I am using Gunicorn (usually with Nginx as a reverse proxy). I start it using ```gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi``` in the root dir. This error that you get means that ```create_app()``` is serialized in some way, which might be specific to apache2.

Comment: Give a look at [this](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/issues-with-pickle-module.html). Apache2 is using mod_wsgi being the scene, which is why you get this issue. I strongly encourage you to use Nginx as a reverse proxy + Gunicorn as for me it was both very simple to setup and it runs flawlessly. Apache is powerful but is quite heavy compare to Nginx

Comment: Still doesn't work. Thank you for your help. I think I might have to look for some other solution to enable multi threading.

Comment: also wanted to add that I cant use Gunicorn because I will have to use a Windows server :(